# getting an error there is no attribute "placeholder" in xhtml strict 1.0

Tags: javascript, html, css

I realize that placeholder is html 5 i believe. Is there an alternative for placeholder?

I have to use xhtml strict 1.0 it's a requirement.

Comment: Yes [**there is**](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=placeholder%20js). Google is a pretty great place to start, don't you think?

Comment: that looks confusing the alternative placeholder= enter link. how would i get the placeholder attribute to bypass in xhtml strict 1.0 with the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xhtml DOES support placeholder because XHTML is a mix of XML & HTML.
The function works but it won't validate because validation methods haven't caught up with new coding principles.
Use this as an alternative which does validate;

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="your placeholder text here" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, placeholder is new to HTML5 so it's not going to work in XHTML and there is no real equivalent. The only thing I could suggest is setting the "value" equal to the placeholder text, but then the user will have to delete the text before inputting their own.

The only other option would be to somehow mimic placeholder text using javascript.

Comment: thats fine, how would i do that? value? it wouldnt matter if the person would have to delete the text before entering input

Comment: it would look like this: 

<input value="name" />

This would create an input box with "name" in the field.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy with [**this library**](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/).

Just include the library in the `<head>` tag of your page (you can also download the file):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js/master/dist/placeholders.min.js"></script>
```

And use a placeholder like you would normally do:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="I have a placeholder!"/>
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: i still get the error   there is no attribute "placeholder" w3c validator using xhtml strict 1.0

Comment: @WilfredoTurner Yup, a validator will warn you about that, but it will still cause no problem running in a browser. That's called a _polyfill_, it adds functionality when it is not available natively.

Comment: oh ok, so i shouldn't get points taken off for these types of errors hopefully

Comment: @WilfredoTurner That's your only alternative, so explain to your teacher that the script ([**Polyfill**](https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill)) adds that functionnality, even if W3C does not recognize it. A lot of websites to this to enhance user experience for legacy browsers. You should be fine if you mention why you did that.

Comment: thanks blex. My professor will overlook this. I explained it to her via email thanks a million .